# How to resolve Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement chromecast feature in my flutter app and I cloned the github repository from https://pub.dev/packages/smart_video_cast. The package name is smart_video_cast. But I got the following error. Could anyone help with this issue? Any help would be highly appreciated.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:2.9.6.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.31.
> Required by:
> project :app > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.31.
> Required by:
> project :app > androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04
> project :app > androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2.
> Required by:
> project :app > androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2.
> Required by:
> project :app > androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04
> 2
> > Skipped due to earlier error

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a `repository` from which `gradle` can download the dependency.

Please, check your `build.gradle` file (**application level**) that contains `google` and `mavenCentral` repositories

Build script section:

```
...
buildscript {
    repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
    }
...

}
```

All projects section:

```
...
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite understand what should I add here??

Comment: Check your app-level build.gradle file(your_flutter_project_path/android/build.gradle)